# What does "llvm/libexec/clang-cc" do?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

Using command `clang -### a.c` can output the commands that `clang a.c`  calls.

For me, it outputs followings on my screen(focus on last three lines):

```
clang version 1.0 (https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/branches/release_26 exported)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/local/bin/llvm+clang-2.6-x86_64-linux/bin/../libexec/clang-cc" "-triple" "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "-S" "-disable-free" "-main-file-name" "a.c" "--relocation-model" "static" "--disable-fp-elim" "--unwind-tables=1" "--mcpu=x86-64" "--fmath-errno=1" "-fdiagnostics-show-option" "-o" "/tmp/cc-yffqSv.s" "-x" "c" "a.c"
 "/usr/bin/gcc" "-c" "-m64" "-o" "/tmp/cc-pa2Qo4.o" "-x" "assembler" "/tmp/cc-yffqSv.s"
 "/usr/bin/gcc" "-m64" "-o" "a.out" "/tmp/cc-pa2Qo4.o"
```

In the line: `/usr/local/bin/llvm+clang-2.6-x86_64-linux/bin/../libexec/clang-cc" "-triple" "x86 ......`, it shows that the command `clang` called this: `/libexec/clang-cc`.

**What does it(file "libexec/clang-cc") do?**

And there is another question related I desired to ask:

**Whether or not: command `clang` uses the front end of the project "clang", and the back end of "gcc"?**

Because I find the last two line of code above called "/usr/bin/gcc".

I have search this for hours, can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC broadly GCC works by transforming the source into an abstract syntax tree (the 'front end'), applying optimisations etc. and then turning that into system-specific assembly ('back end'). So by those definitions you're using clang for both front end and back end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using quite an old version of Clang. You might want to try a newer one.

`clang-cc` is the clang C compiler, which converts a C program to assembly language. [Note 1]. Depending on version and target, it may also be able to directly produce an object file. See the `-integrated-as` command-line flag.

If your version of Clang does not have an assembler for your target architecture, the `clang` driver will try to use the system assembler (and linker). On some systems, these will be part of Gcc, although there are other options.

---

#### Notes

1. Clang actually first compiles C (or other C-like languages) into platform-neutral LLVM Intermediate Representation (IR), and then uses the LLVM library to convert that into optimised platform-specific assembler code. These two parts are what are generally referred to as the Clang "front-end" (C⇒LLVM) and "back-end" (LLVM⇒Assembler). These are not separate programs

Answer (score 2):

> What does it(file "libexec/clang-cc") do?

Its output `"-o" "/tmp/cc-yffqSv.s"` suggests it outputs assembly.

> and the back end of "gcc"?

The last two lines with `gcc` invocations are:

1. Generate an object file from the assembly.
2. Link object files into `a.out`.

Comment: Thanks, I am now trying to find a equivalent approach to do what "the first line" do, using tools like "llvm-as" and "opt". Is there any possibility to do that?